# javascript create nested JSON array from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, nested

I have this array :
myArray = [ "Id = 1", "Time = 18:40", "Topic = yyyyyyyyyyyy", "GUEST", "Role = HS", "Infos = Arizona", "Role = GS", "Infos = Arizona", "Role = GS", "Infos = Colorado", "Id = 2","Time = 11:32", "Topic = xoxo", "GUEST", "Role" = "GS",      "Infos = California", "Role = CS", "Infos = Maryland", "Role = GS","Infos = Nevada" ];

I want to create a nested JSON array from it:

```
myJson = [
{  
 "Id" : "1",
 "Time" : "18:40",
 "Topic" : "yyyyyyyyyyyy",
 "GUEST":
 [
   {"Role" : "HS",
   "Infos" : "Arizona"},
   {"Role" : "GS",
   "Infos" : "Arizona"},
   {"Role" : "HS",
   "Infos" : "Colorado"}
 ]
},
{  
 "Id" : "2",
 "Time" : "11:32",
 "Topic" : "xoxo",
 "GUEST":
 [
   {"Role" : "GS",
   "Infos" : "California"},
   {"Role" : "CS",
   "Infos" : "Maryland"},
   {"Role" : "GS",
   "Infos" : "Nevada"}
 ]
}
]
```

How can I do it? tried the code below without success.

```js
myArray = ["Id = 1","Time = 18:40","Topic = yyyyyyyyyyyy","GUEST","Role = HS","Infos = Arizona","Role = GS","Infos = Arizona","Role = GS","Infos = Colorado","Id = 2","Time = 11:32","Topic = xoxo","GUEST","Role" = "GS","Infos = California","Role = CS","Infos = Maryland","Role = GS","Infos = Nevada"];

// Declaring new object
   let obj = {};
   // Place to remember current level of object
   let level;
   myJson = [];
   for (let item of this.myArray) {
     // If it contains an equals
     if (item.includes('=')) {
       // Split it into two stings
       let split = item.split('=');
       let key = split[0].trim();
       let val = split[1].trim();
       // If we're already on a lower level like GUEST3 put it in there
       if (level) {
         obj[level][key] = val
       } else {
         // Or just place the new data at the top level
         obj[key] = val
       }
     } else {
       // If there's no equals we want to go down a layer
       level = item;
       myJson.push(obj[item]);
     }
   }

console.log("myJson : "+ JSON.stringify(myJson));
```

Comment: it is an array of json. I tried updating post but it is not letting me updated it but is :` "GUEST":
` [
  { "Role" : "HS",
   "Infos" : "Arizona"},
   {"Role" : "GS",
   "Infos" : "Arizona"},
  { "Role" : "HS",
   "Infos" : "Colorado"}
 ]` this is what it should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another answer is totally right - format you are requesting is totally wrong. *If* it would have been just going one object deeper when you meet "GUEST" string and create new object in the output when you meet next `"Id = \d+"` string, you could use something like:

```
  let process = (arr) => {
    let path = [];
    const data = [];
    let o = data;
    while (arr && arr.length) {
      let item = arr.shift();
      let key= null;
      let value = null;

      if (/Id = \d+/.test(item)) {
        o = {};
        data.push(o);
        let pair = item.split(' = ');
        o.Id = pair[1];      
      } 
      else if (item == "GUEST") {
        o["GUEST"] = {};
        o = o["GUEST"]      
        value = {};      
      } else {
        let pair = item.split(' = ');
        o[pair[0]] = pair[1];       
      }      
    }  
    return data;
  }
```

However with this approach your duplicate keys will get overriden like so:

```
 [
    {
      "Id": "1",
      "Time": "18:40",
      "Topic": "yyyyyyyyyyyy",
      "GUEST": {
        "Role": "GS",
        "Infos": "Colorado"
      }
    },
    {
      "Id": "2",
      "Time": "11:32",
      "Topic": "xoxo",
      "GUEST": {
        "Role": "GS",
        "Infos": "Nevada"
      }
    }
  ]
```

I think this is a good start and you can fine tune parsing GUEST part up to your liking

Comment: ok, thanks. *your duplicate keys will get overriden* was helpful info. I know why my code seems to not work since I were just getting the last JSON guest. thank you for explaining.

Answer (score -1):

JSON's format is wrong.

1. Key-value pair array is not allowed in JSON.
2. Key-value pair array cannot have same name key.

**Change to the following format (JSON has strict requirements on the format)：**

```js
myJson = [
{  
 "Id" : "1",
 "Time" : "18:40",
 "Topic" : "yyyyyyyyyyyy",
 "GUEST":
 [
   {
     "Role" : "HS",
     "Infos" : "Arizona"
   },
   {
     "Role" : "GS",
     "Infos" : "Arizona"
   },
   {
     "Role" : "HS",
    "Infos" : "Colorado"
   }
 ]
}
]
```

Comment: This does not remotely answer the question - OP was asking *how* to transform his data (with Javascript code), not for suggestions on what his output should look like. If you need clarification from OP on the requirements before providing an answer to his question, ask or suggest such in a *comment*, not in an answer.